# ARCore Models Spawning slightly underneath of detected plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I've been able to spawn gameobjects in using ARCore but for some reason it keeps going a bit through the detected plane. Am I suppose to attach a script to the gameobject (because I saw in an old tutorial that you used to attach a script called "Plane Attachment" but that script isn't in the GoogleARCore folder)

Another thing, is there a way I could make the plane invisible as soon as I spawn a model in?

Comment: How do you spawn objects? Do you anchor them? You can prevent planes to be rendered by modifying detected plane generator or visualizer